# Simple voice chat application for Yahoo in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: software-recommendation

I just need a simple voice chat via yahoo. I tried Empathy, Kopete, Pidgin and read several forums, but none helped.

Can anyone give me a hint how can I make a simple audio call via yahoo in Ubuntu 11.04? Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried gYachE or gYachi ? I'll reply back in 2/3 hrs if its available for 11.04 and way to set it up. I used it around a year back so not sure if its still available but u can try until then :)

Comment: I read about it but as I checked its website, it is very old. Moreover, I was unable to find it in Ubuntu Software Center, and thought that it should not be popular recently.

Comment: `Gyache` Its available through `ppa:adilson/experimental` ppa. I donot know how much progress it has made but it is under active development so give it a try.

Comment: It can be left open for others; though I resolved my problem by using web-based google talk. I installed lots of applications, and do not aim to make my ubuntu more messy ;)

Comment: I thought you had a problem with connecting to Yahoo. Web-based Google Talk solves it!?

Comment: no, I switched from Yahoo to Google Talk ... still I'm interested to find a way to use Yahoo; but no more try-and-error

Comment: Are you using 64-bit?

Comment: no I'm on 32-bit

Answer (score 2):

Try the guide at http://www.technixupdate.com/download-yahoo-messenger-for-ubuntu-linux-with-webcam-voice-chat-photo-sharing-support/ for getting yahoo messenger on linux with voice chat, webcam support, etc. It has screenshots and clear instructions, and I hope it works for you.

Comment: That article is to be updated for oneric

Comment: It should work fine on oneric.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Nitstorm, I can't seem to get it into my post. The formatting gets messed up, hyperlinks get all weird, etc. I looked all over the askubuntu site, but couldn't seem to get the information I needed to get the "essential parts" from the website to here without it getting all weird. Anyways, hope it's useful as is, and that it works!

Comment: http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Chat/Yahoo-Messenger-2.shtml the app is from 2005 :)

Comment: @ Lilan A. Moraru That guide is from 2009, not 2005 :D

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many like: pidgin and empathy and can be easily installed using apt-get/ubuntu software center. Pidgin also supports video chatting for yahoo.

These work very nicely. Instead of looking for alternatives it is better to sort the problem with these by exactly knowing what issues are being faced.

Comment: *Pidgin also supports video chatting for yahoo.* Do you have a specific Pidgin version for Linux which can do Yahoo voice? Which one is it? If not, could you please give a citation supporting this claim? https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/9735 doesn't show any progress on this feature and most of the web sites I've fond say the contrary.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145228/audio-video-options-disabled-in-pidgin-when-using-yahoo-voice-video says that Pidgin does not support voice or video for Yahoo. This directly contradicts what you say. Do you have any evidence supporting your claim? How did you manage to make it work?

Comment: According to https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+question/139747 , Empathy doesn't support Yahoo voice chat either. Empathy uses Telepathy for network communication, and  the official page http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Protocols%20Support of Telepathy says that Yahoo voice chat is not supported.