#  Audio / Video Options disabled in Pidgin when using Yahoo Voice Video

Tags: pidgin, yahoo

Please help me rightly configure my pidgin to enable yahoo voice/video.
Pidgin version 2.10.3
Conversation > Media > Audio / Video Options are disabled :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Pidgin does not support voice/video for Yahoo! Messenger. [This feature has been requested years ago but has still not been implemented.](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/9735)

Another application, [GYachI](http://gyachi.sourceforge.net/), does have this functionality, so you might consider using that if you need to use Yahoo!'s instant messaging service for voice and video chat. Or you could use a different protocol/service for this that is supported in Pidgin.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like GYachI has been maintained much recently. So you may or may not get it to work either. If you're running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, you can install it with [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~loell/+archive/ppa). ([Read this first though, so you understand the risks of PPA's and how to judge whether or not a PPA is safe.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)) Otherwise, you'll have to build the program from source. To do this, download the source code by choosing the source code option on the [GYachI downloads page](http://gyachi.sourceforge.net/download.shtml). If you don't know how to build a program from source on Ubuntu, see [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) and/or [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware).

Answer (score 1):

From Pidgin's [FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#VoiceandVideoMicrophoneandWebcamSupport):

> **Does Pidgin support voice or video?**
>  Yes, Pidgin does support voice and video, but this is limited to Unix-like platforms and the
>   XMPP protocol (including GoogleTalk).

Yahoo uses its own protocol, so the answer to your question is that, unfortunately, you can't enable Yahoo voice and video chat with Pidgin for the simple reason that **it's not implemented** for now.